# Preference for adding epub to iBooks

Tags: preferences, books

In iTunes it was/is possible to prevent files to be copied to iTunes Media folder. Does any of you know if same de-selection is possible in iBooks?

Thanks for lot of useful knowledge sharing

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Books added to iBooks are stored in a folder by the application automatically.