# Open ePub in iBooks for Mac without adding it to the iBooks library

Tags: macos, books

(Possibly a duplicate of [Preference for adding epub to iBooks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119612/preference-for-adding-epub-to-ibooks))

Is it possible to use iBooks on Mavericks to open an ePub without adding it to the library?

Possibly through `defaults`?

(`defaults read -app iBooks` spits out

```
{
    BKAlreadyDisplayedWelcomeExperience = 1;
    "BKBookViewerPlugInInstanceDescriptor.1849B0F38A4F4340765773EE6EB5BFA6" =     {
        NotesPanelVisible = 0;
        "saved-window-frame" = "353 94 1075 782 0 0 1680 1028 ";
    };
    "BKBookViewerPlugInInstanceDescriptor.A73B9E1E327A40C8EE40A9A12DF688AA" =     {
        NotesPanelVisible = 0;
        "saved-window-frame" = "302 125 1075 782 0 0 1680 1028 ";
    };
    "BKBookshelfCategoryManager~012384" = 0;
    BKBookshelfViewControllerFilterAction = 5;
    BKBookshelfViewControllerSortAction = 1;
    BKEPubViewerColorTheme = 0;
    "BKStyleManagerLastFont-" = "Iowan Old Style";
    CachedStorefrontID = "143441-1,22 ab:BKDB";
    CachedStorefrontRedirectID = "143441-1,22 ab:BKDB";
    CachedStorefrontRedirectURL = "https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewGrouping?cc=us&id=27820&mt=11";
    CachedStorefrontURL = "https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewEbooksMain";
    "IMPlugInInstanceDescriptor.7" =     {
        "saved-window-frame" = "541 130 1024 724 0 0 1680 1028 ";
    };
    "IMPlugInInstanceDescriptor.8" =     {
        "saved-window-frame" = "328 238 1024 724 0 0 1680 1028 ";
    };
    LibraryCountDate = "2014-05-06 02:34:49 +0000";
    "MZBookKeeper.LastDsid" = 1026970190;
    "MZBookKeeper.LastDsidText" = "hawkrives@gmail.com";
    NSPreferencesSelectedIndex = 0;
    "NSToolbar Configuration NSPreferences" =     {
        "TB Default Item Identifiers" =         (
            General,
            Store,
            Parental
        );
        "TB Display Mode" = 1;
        "TB Icon Size Mode" = 1;
        "TB Is Shown" = 1;
        "TB Item Identifiers" =         (
            NSToolbarFlexibleSpaceItem,
            General,
            Store,
            Parental,
            NSToolbarFlexibleSpaceItem
        );
        "TB Size Mode" = 1;
    };
    "NSWindow Frame Preferences" = "66 164 593 390 0 0 1680 1028 ";
    "primary.WebKit2AcceleratedDrawingEnabled" = 1;
    "primary.WebKit2DeveloperExtrasEnabled" = 1;
    "primary.WebKit2SuppressesIncrementalRendering" = 1;
}
```

but I don't see anything that looks useful.)

Comment: Not an answer to your question , but you could avoid iBooks and use, for example, Clearview to read epubs.